# Two querys with same execution time, but different execution time inside an insert

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, query-optimization

So, I have two selects, that costs the same amount of time ~2,5 minutes. But when I try insert into... select(query1) and insert into... select(query2), one takes a lot of time more than the other.

The only difference between the two query is a case, with the case being inside an inner join or outside.

I really don´t know why there is so much performance difference.

I tried the first one and it only takes like 5 minutes to insert. And the second one never goes to an end, being active for more than an hour. The amount of rows to insert is around 5 million.

Comment: How do you suppose we can divine what is going on there? You are aware that `INSERT` cannot use parallel query, aren't you?

Comment: I´m not doing it in a parallel query, first i do query1 and when it´s finished I truncate the table and try the same with query2 to see the difference

Comment: There is a lot of missing context here so I don't feel able to write a good answer. I think you need to show us the SQL (appropriately reformatted/reduced to a minimal reproducible example). My understanding is that these are two different SELECT statements to retrieve the same data and insert it into the same table, but if any of that's not true then it would be important to say so.

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.